Where is the signature of a signed APK stored?
I do research on methods to modify .apk in order to add some protection. I understand that all protection code can be removed, but at least it will temporarily protect against auto-patches, for example, patches for the ApkEditor or MT Manager apps.
One of the cases to modify is the PmsHookApplication class (example of detection), which becomes a proxy for the Application class to hook calls to PackageManager.getPackageInfo and returns the original signature. This works for older Android APIs. Since version 28+, the GET_SIGNATURES flag has been deprecated, so the old version of the hook does not work for the new GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES flag. Is there any successor to this method? I have not been able to find any new ways. If you know of any, please let me know. It would be helpful to know what "traces" are left after APK re-signing.
My question is connected with the PmsHookApplication patch. It gets the signature from the META-INF/.RSA file and returns it with the call to PackageManager.getPackageInfo. However, when I migrate the signing scheme from version 1 to 2, files like .RSA and .SF, do not appear in the META-INF folder of the apk archive.
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file('.jks')
        storePassword ''
        keyAlias ''
        keyPassword ''
        enableV1Signing false
        enableV2Signing true
        enableV3Signing true
     }
}

On the other hand the apksigner tool tells that the apk was signed successfully. In the scheme version 2, where is the new place to store the signature that can be read by hacker? Because he can do the same thing: hook and return original signature. Or has something changed and this method is no longer possible?
> apksigner verify --verbose app-name.apk

Verifies
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): false
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): true
Verified using v3.1 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3.1): false
Verified using v4 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v4): false
Verified for SourceStamp: false
Number of signers: 1


To my knowledge if you call PackageManager from within an app to query details about your or other apps the APK is not read at all. Android only verifies the APK signature upon installation and the saves the extracted information to a central XML file (or may be a database in newer versions). Note that if you want to verify signature yourself Google provides the apksig library via Maven/Gradle. This library is the code base of apksigner therefore you can use it to verify APK files.

@Robert I ask because a patch like PmsHookApplication hooks PackageManager and returns a valid signature. So I want to verify at runtime via side-effects from a crack. And in case the version is 1, I understand where the original signature is obtained. Now I am looking for new places of signature to protect app features from modification if my hidden conditions find evidence of the crack. For example, "anti-check": if a positive result is received to a request with an incorrect signature, there is a high chance that the hacker simply returned true from the verification function.

As I wrote you don't need to look for the new places of the signature. Just include and use apksig library in your app and you can get the same data as printed by apksigner verify --verbose. No need to re-implement the wheel.

https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/apksigning/v2
android extends the zip format to include the signature. there is no file name for it so it can't be read using tools that only understand standard zip.

The ZIP format is not really extended, Google simply uses a "gap" in the ZIP format where you can include data in a ZIP file that is not covered by the ZIP spec.

@Robert - you're making a distinction without a difference. literally every element defined by the zip specification also occupies a "gap" that would be otherwise meaningless. it's called backwards compatibility.
